# VB script causing IIS to crash

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a VBscript on a ASP page that creates a PDF file from a SQL db, but for some reason it crashes the IIS after some times or after several users use it at the same time.

Here is the code of the ASP page:

```
<%@ Language=VBScript %>

<%
    on error resume next
        
    Function ReadBinaryFile(FileName)
        Const adTypeBinary = 1

        'Create Stream object
        Dim BinaryStream
        Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")

        'Specify stream type - we want To get binary data.
        BinaryStream.Type = adTypeBinary       

        'Open the stream
        BinaryStream.Open       

        'Load the file data from disk To stream object
        BinaryStream.LoadFromFile FileName       

        'Open the stream And get binary data from the object
        ReadBinaryFile = BinaryStream.Read
        
        'Close stream
        BinaryStream.Close
        set BinaryStream = nothing  

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Response.Write "Error: " & Err.Number
        Response.Write "Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number)
        Response.Write "Source: " &  Err.Source
        Response.Write "Description: " &  Err.Description
        Response.End
        End If
            
    End Function 
    
    
    Response.Buffer = true
    Response.Expires = 0
    Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"
    
    Tipo = Request.QueryString("Tabla")
    Folio = Request.QueryString("Documento")
    
    sPath = server.MapPath("/ecommerce/download")
    sName = "" & Tipo & "_" & replace(Folio,"-","_") & ".pdf"
    
    sFile = sPath & "\" & sName
    
    sFormato = Session("Var").GetValor(cstr("FTO_IMP_" & Tipo & ""),0)
        
    if sFormato = "" then   
        Response.Write "DEBE CONFIGURAR UN FORMATO DE IMPRESION, VARIABLE FTO_IMP_'" & Tipo & "' "
        Response.End
    end if
    
    aValor = split(sFormato,",")
    
    If aValor(0) = "" then  
        Response.Write "DEBE CONFIGURAR UN FORMATO DE IMPRESION, VARIABLE FTO_IMP_'" & Tipo & "'"
        Response.End
    End If
    
    If  Tipo = "FACTURA" then
        sValor = aValor(0)
    Else
        sValor = aValor(1)
    End if
    
    Session("Var").Memoria = sPath
    Set Pr = Server.CreateObject("impresionPRO.Impresion")  
    Pr.Imprimir_Formato cstr(sValor),cstr(Folio),cstr("PDF"),true,true,cstr(sFile)
    Set Pr = Nothing

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Response.Write "Error: " & Err.Number
        Response.Write "Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number)
        Response.Write "Source: " &  Err.Source
        Response.Write "Description: " &  Err.Description
        Response.End
        End If
    
    Dim vntStream
    
    vntStream = ReadBinaryFile(sFile)
    
    response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
    Response.AddHeader "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & sName
    Response.BinaryWrite(vntStream)
    Set oMyObject = Nothing
    Set vntStream = Nothing
    
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Response.Write "Error: " & Err.Number
        Response.Write "Error (Hex): " & Hex(Err.Number)
        Response.Write "Source: " &  Err.Source
        Response.Write "Description: " &  Err.Description
        Response.End
        End If
    
    Response.End
```

The event viwer shows the following:

> Name of application errors: w3wp.exe, version: 8.5.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52157ba0
>
> Faulting module name: MSVBVM60.DLL version: 6.0.98.32, time stamp: 0x4eb1c425
>
> Exception code: 0xc0000005
>
> Displacement error: 0x0003ae9a
>
> ID of the process with errors: 0x1360
>
> Start time of application errors: 0x01d1375392dc3524
>
> Path of application errors: C: \ Windows \ SysWOW64 \ inetsrv \ w3wp.exe
>
> Path module with errors: C: \ Windows \ System32 \ MSVBVM60.DLL
>
> Report ID: 0f2a7a3c-A34E-11e5-8119-000c2964cc30
>
> Full package name with errors:
>
> Relative Identifier application package with errors:

Comment: maybe you should `BinaryStream.Close` before `Set BinaryStream = Nothing`

Comment: Probably a "file opened" issue. instead of just relying on the `on error resume next` command to bypass everything. You need some error to determine where exactly the problem is. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692852.aspx

Comment: The solution of @WhiteHat seems to have minimized the error. It used to happen every 15 minutes, now it has only happened twice in the last 5 hours.

Comment: Put your error handler around your code, not simply as a cover all. Block off distinct areas and see what it's catching.

Comment: I've added some code to show the error, but doesn't seem to work. Every time the error presents, the page just shows a mesage saying the page has some scripting error.